# How to make a button in an iframe trigger a function on a specific object in the parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following 2 html files, INDEX.HTML and FRAME.HTML, which is shown in an iframe on INDEX.HTML. When I click button1, I get the alert "action1: your value 1". A click on button2 shows the alert "action1: your value 2".

My question is, how can I make an onclick on button3 that triggers action2 on the myfunction object bound to button1? This should give me the alert "action2: your value 1".

INDEX.HTML:

```
    <a id="button1" href="#">BUTTON 1</a>
    <a id="button2" href="#">BUTTON 2</a>

    <iframe id="frameforbutton3" src="frame.html"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $.fn.myfunction = function(value) {
            $(this).click(function() {
                action1();
                return false;
            });
            var action1 = function() {
                alert("action1: " + value);
            }
            var action2 = function() {
                alert("action2: " + value);
            }
        }
        $(function() {
            $("#button1").myfunction("your value 1");
            $("#button2").myfunction("your value 2");
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
```

FRAME.HTML:

```
    <a id="button3" href="#">BUTTON 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution that seems to work as desired. No matter how many elements I bind myfunction to on my page, the number of global variables and/or functions will remain constant. Exactly what I wanted to achieve. Here are my modifications.

INDEX.HTML:

```
    <a id="button1" href="#">BUTTON 1</a>
    <a id="button2" href="#">BUTTON 2</a>

    <iframe id="frameforbutton3" src="frame.html"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var buttons = {};
        $.fn.myfunction = function(value) {
            var button = $(this);
            buttons[button.attr('id')] = myfunctionimpl(button, value);
        }
        var myfunctionimpl = function(button, value) {
            button.click(function() {
                action1();
                return false;
            });
            var action1 = function() {
                alert("action1: " + value);
            }
            var action2 = function() {
                alert("action2: " + value);
            }
            return {
                action2: action2
            }
        }
        $(function() {
            $("#button1").myfunction("your value 1");
            $("#button2").myfunction("your value 2");
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
```

FRAME.HTML:

```
    <a id="button3" href="#" onclick="window.parent.buttons['button1'].action2(); return false;">BUTTON 3</a>
```

A click on button3 shows the alert "action2: your value 1".

Answer (score 1):

You can't access elements of the parent frame from within the frame, or vice versa. What you *can* do is have a function within the parent that is called by the child. In the parent add:

```
function clickButton(num) {
    $("#button" + num).click();
}
```

...then from the child (frame.html), call:

```
window.parent.clickButton(1);
```

...or 2, depending on your need.

Comment: Almost. Your example would call action1 and not action2. But I guess I could render hidden buttons that trigger action2 and then use this approach. I just wish I could wrap your clickButton(num) function in the myfunction object to avoid name collisions. This was one of the reasons I went with $.fn. But also the source of the problem.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Fortunately, you don't have to use it to click buttons. You can have it call any function you want. Your code as it stands doesn't expose action2 in any way, so I can't really show you an example of executing it. Also, you can't assign $.fn.myfunction to an element in the frame (even if you expose it via the method I've given) because $.fn.function can't access a DOM element within another frame.

Comment: I guess the question is, how to best expose action2. So far your suggestion is the best I've got, if I render a hidden button, bind action2 to its click event and make a function like yours click it from the iframe. Then the only question is how I best name a global function so it doesn't collide with other functions. It's not going the be the prettiest thing in the world, but it will work.

Comment: Right. Or, take action2 out of the `$.fn` wrapper. It doesn't sound like it really belongs there, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the element inside the iframe with :

```
var button3 = $('iframe#frameforbutton3').contents().find("#button3");
```

then you can add an evenlistener :

```
button3.myfunction("your value 3");
```

or directly :

```
$('iframe#frameforbutton3').contents().find("#button3").myfunction("your value 3");
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand this correct, this will set an onclick event on button3 that triggers action1(). Furthermore, even if it did trigger action2() somehow, it would do so on the myfunction object bound to button3 and not the object bound to button1 in the parent frame. The result would be the alert "action2: your value 3" and not "action2: your value 1" as desired.